# jQuery Function GIving Odd Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery function that works without error on a Desktop browser, but throws an error on an iPad or iPhone. When I run the console to find the error I get this message. I'm sorry I not giving you guys much to go on. I can provide more information if you let me know what you are looking for.

**EDIT:** I've disabled all other plugins. Take note that this code works fine on computer browsers, but not on mobile devices; specifically iPads and iPhones.

**EDIT_2:** I just found this code in my page. It seems that if the browser is from a mobile device it won't load some of the plugins. New question, is there a reason why my theme would restrict the loading of these plugins?

```
var ismobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
        if(!ismobile){

            /** ONLY EXECUTE THESE CODES IF MOBILE DETECTION IS FALSE **/

            /* REQUIRED: Datatable PDF/Excel output componant */

            document.write('<script src="js/include/ZeroClipboard.min.js"><\/script>');
            document.write('<script src="js/include/TableTools.min.js"><\/script>');
            document.write('<script src="js/include/select2.min.js"><\/script>');
            document.write('<script src="js/include/jquery.excanvas.min.js"><\/script>');
            document.write('<script src="js/include/jquery.placeholder.min.js"><\/script>');
```

---

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".themed select.with-search").select2()')
```

Here is the code it is complaining about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setup_custom_form_elements();
    });

    function setup_custom_form_elements() {
            if ($('.themed').length) {
                $(".themed input[type='radio'], .themed input[type='checkbox'], .themed input[type='file'].file, .themed textarea").uniform();
                $(".themed select.with-search").select2();

                /* some demo buttons for select 2 */

                $("#disable-select-demo").click(function() {
                    $("#select-demo-js select").select2("disable");
                });

                $("#enable-select-demo").click(function() {
                    $("#select-demo-js select.with-search").select2();
                });

            }// end if
    }
```

Comment: evaluating? What? where? I dont see any eval statement??

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: Are you using [select2 plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/select2/)? Your error is probably related to that plugin.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal - he means when the script engine is evaluating the line of code he's shown us, and he's using the select2 plugin.

Comment: make sure you are adding select2 js file properly. Check f.i. you are not loading it from an url that hat localhost in it etc.

Comment: I've disabled all other plugins.

Comment: It is being added properly because Safari, Firefox, and Chrome all render it just fine. The problem is on a mobile device, specifically iPads and iPhones that I get the error and it breaks.

Comment: make sure `$` is defined.

Comment: How would I make sure $ is defined?

Comment: By adding jquery to your code. Just load Jquery in your code

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal & matewka & MichalRybak Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:
As mentioned above, my theme was restricting the loading of the plugin's source file. Stupid mistake, I should have noticed it. I have taken the Select2 plugin out of the `if(!mobile)` statement and now everything works just fine. 
Thanks for all the help guys!